# Parsing multiple root XML file in Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am a beginner in Python.
I use Python 2.7 with ElementTree to parse XML files.
I have a big XML file (~700 MB), which contains multiple root instances, for example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> <foo> <bar> <sometag> Mehdi  </sometag> <someothertag> blahblahblah </someothertag> . . . </bar> </foo>
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> <foo> <bar> <sometag> Hamidi </sometag> <someothertag> blahblahblah </someothertag> . . . </bar> </foo>
...
...
```

each xml instance is placed in one line.
I need to parse such file in python. I used ElementTree this way:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('filename.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

but it seems it just can access to the first root XML instance line.
What is the proper way to parse all XML instances in this type of file?

Comment: That's not valid XML. Split the file in single lines and parse each line as an XML document. Use `manyLinesString.split('\n')`.

Comment: As @ThomasWeller said, this is not a valid XML. Ans as I see this, you have two options: (1) build your XML properly or (2) if it is possible - read the line and parse every line as a different XML.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse("file.xml").getroot()
getpid = root.iter("bar")
```

Also you can check online for xml validate.
https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lxml.etree.iterparse() method also, it works pretty fast. It is suggested by IBM- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/

```
for _, elem in etree.iterparse("filename.xml"):
    if elem.tag == 'bar':
        print(elem.text)
    elem.clear()
```